# Jenkins - Sqlplus script runner plugin - unable to load shared libraries

Tags: oracle, jenkins, plugins, sqlplus

I am stuck defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH in sqlplus plugin, the same was working without plugin but in shell executor. Now after installing the plugin i have no idea where to define LD_LIBRARY_PATH. please help me out.

My oracle 12 is a lite version and lib files are lying inside /12.1.0.2/client_1/

> [svc-reim@dvreiappca001uk ~]$ cd
>   /appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/ [svc-reim@dvreiappca001uk
>   client_1]$ ls adrci                  libheteroxa12.so 
>   liboramysql12.so  ojdbc6.jar cfgtoollogs            libipc1.so
>   libsqlplus.so     oraInst.loc install                libmql1.so
>   libsqlplusic.so   orai18n-mapping.jar inventory
>   libnnz12.so       libsqora.so.12.1  orai18n.jar jdbc
>   libocci.so.12.1   light             sqlplus lib
>   libociei.so       network           uidrvci libclntsh.so.12.1
>   libocijdbc12.so   nls               wrc libclntshcore.so.12.1 
>   libons.so         odbc              xstreams.jar
>   [svc-reim@dvreiappca001uk client_1]$

Please find my Jenkins job error -

> Getting ORACLE_HOME... Using custom SQL*Plus location SQL*Plus >>>
>   /appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/sqlplus Using custom TNS_ADMIN
>   location TNS_ADMIN >>>
>   /appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/network/admin
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- Using custom ORACLE_HOME
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- Using ORACLE_HOME =/appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- Getting SQLPlus version [ReIM16_CustomScripts] $
>   /appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/sqlplus -v
>   /appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/sqlplus: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory Process exited with status 127
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read SQL script
>   [/GFR/DB_ReIM16/ReIM16_CustomScripts]  !  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplusscriptrunner.SQLPlusRunner.run(SQLPlusRunner.java:216)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplusscriptrunner.SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.perform(SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.java:112)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)  at
>   hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:496)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421) ERROR: Unable to read
>   SQL script [/GFR/DB_ReIM16/ReIM16_CustomScripts]  !

Please help me out on how to set Lib path in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to set the `ORACLE_HOME` correctly

[image: config]

I think you should set it to `/appl/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/`

Answer (score 0):

Set it as an environment variable 
[Linux] export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/product/12.1.0.2/client_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH